# Django: how to annotate average of average?

Tags: group-by, django-queryset, django-orm, django-annotate, django-aggregation

I have a `Puzzle` model and a `Session` model

During a session, user will play puzzles and rate them. result is recorded through the following model:

```py
class Play(models.Model):
    puzzle = models.ForeignKey(
            'puzzles.Puzzle', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='plays')
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session, blank=True,
                                null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='plays')
```

a same puzzle can be played more than once during the same session.

I'm trying to annotate the Session.objects with the `rating_avg_from_session_plays` which is averaging the `rating_average_by_puzzle`.
in other terms:

1. for each puzzle played during the session, I want to obtain the average `rating` (`avg_pzl_rating`)
2. and I want afterwards, for each session, I want to average these `avg_pzl_rating` to obtain the average session rating (`avg_session_pzl_rating`)

Using `Subquery` and `group_by` syntaxes, I've not been able so far to achieve the expected result.

Here is the closest I've reached:

```py
rating_average_by_puzzle_from_session_plays = Subquery(Play.objects.filter(session_id=OuterRef(
                'id')).values('puzzle_id').order_by('puzzle_id').annotate(
                puzzle_rating_average=Avg('rating')).values('puzzle_rating_average'))
    
Session.objects.annotate(rating_avg_from_session_plays=Avg(rating_average_by_puzzle_from_session_plays))
```

What Am I doing wrong ?
from the result it appears like only the first `rating` is taken into account, while the following on a `Session` object is working very well:

```py
session_object.plays.values('puzzle_id').order_by('puzzle_id').annotate(
           puzzle_rating_average=Avg('rating')).aggregate(
           rating_average=Avg('puzzle_rating_average'))['rating_average'] or 0
```

here is the corresponding sql request sent to the database when I'm trying to annotate the `Session` queryset:

```sql
    SELECT "games_session"."id", "games_session"."datetime", "games_session"."rating_average", 
    "games_session"."user_id", AVG((SELECT AVG(U0."rating") AS "puzzle_rating_average"             
    FROM "games_play" U0 WHERE U0."session_id" = "games_session"."id" 
    GROUP BY U0."puzzle_id")) AS "rating_avg_from_session_plays" FROM "games_session" 
    GROUP BY "games_session"."id", "games_session"."datetime", "games_session"."rating_average", 
    "games_session"."user_id"
```

As requested by willeM_ Van Onsem, here is a fixture (json) to illustrate an example of data to be averaged:

```
[
{
    "model": "games.play",
    "pk": 207,
    "fields": {
        "puzzle": 104,
        "rating": 1,
        "session": 2
    }
},
{
    "model": "games.play",
    "pk": 208,
    "fields": {
        "puzzle": 104,
        "rating": 1,
        "session": 2
    }
},
{
    "model": "games.play",
    "pk": 209,
    "fields": {
        "puzzle": 104,
        "rating": 1,
        "session": 2
    }
},
{
    "model": "games.play",
    "pk": 210,
    "fields": {
        "puzzle": 104,
        "rating": 1,
        "session": 2
    }
},
{
    "model": "games.play",
    "pk": 211,
    "fields": {
        "puzzle": 104,
        "rating": 1,
        "session": 2
    }
},
{
    "model": "games.play",
    "pk": 212,
    "fields": {
        "puzzle": 104,
        "rating": 1,
        "session": 2
    }
},
{
    "model": "games.play",
    "pk": 213,
    "fields": {
        "puzzle": 105,
        "rating": 1,
        "session": 2
    }
},
{
    "model": "games.play",
    "pk": 214,
    "fields": {
        "puzzle": 105,
        "rating": 1,
        "session": 2
    }
},
{
    "model": "games.play",
    "pk": 215,
    "fields": {
        "puzzle": 106,
        "rating": 2,
        "session": 2
    }
},
{
    "model": "games.play",
    "pk": 218,
    "fields": {
        "puzzle": 107,
        "rating": 3,
        "session": 2
    }
},
{
    "model": "games.play",
    "pk": 220,
    "fields": {
        "puzzle": 109,
        "rating": 3,
        "session": 2
    }
},
{
    "model": "games.play",
    "pk": 224,
    "fields": {
        "puzzle": 113,
        "rating": 1,
        "session": 2
    }
},
{
    "model": "games.play",
    "pk": 225,
    "fields": {
        "puzzle": 114,
        "rating": 1,
        "session": 2
    }
},
{
    "model": "games.play",
    "pk": 232,
    "fields": {
        "puzzle": 108,
        "rating": 2,
        "session": 2
    }
},
{
    "model": "games.play",
    "pk": 233,
    "fields": {
        "puzzle": 110,
        "rating": 3,
        "session": 2
    }
},
{
    "model": "games.play",
    "pk": 246,
    "fields": {
        "puzzle": 111,
        "rating": 3,
        "session": 2
    }
},
{
    "model": "games.play",
    "pk": 247,
    "fields": {
        "puzzle": 112,
        "rating": 2,
        "session": 2
    }
},
{
    "model": "games.play",
    "pk": 248,
    "fields": {
        "puzzle": 115,
        "rating": 2,
        "session": 2
    }
},
{
    "model": "games.play",
    "pk": 510,
    "fields": {
        "puzzle": 104,
        "rating": 1,
        "session": 2
    }
},
{
    "model": "games.play",
    "pk": 511,
    "fields": {
        "puzzle": 105,
        "rating": 2,
        "session": 2
    }
},
{
    "model": "games.play",
    "pk": 512,
    "fields": {
        "puzzle": 106,
        "rating": 2,
        "session": 2
    }
},
{
    "model": "games.play",
    "pk": 513,
    "fields": {
        "puzzle": 107,
        "rating": 3,
        "session": 2
    }
},
{
    "model": "games.play",
    "pk": 514,
    "fields": {
        "puzzle": 108,
        "rating": 3,
        "session": 2
    }
},
{
    "model": "games.play",
    "pk": 515,
    "fields": {
        "puzzle": 109,
        "rating": 3,
        "session": 2
    }
},
{
    "model": "games.play",
    "pk": 516,
    "fields": {
        "puzzle": 110,
        "rating": 3,
        "session": 2
    }
},
{
    "model": "games.play",
    "pk": 517,
    "fields": {
        "puzzle": 111,
        "rating": 3,
        "session": 2
    }
},
{
    "model": "games.play",
    "pk": 518,
    "fields": {
        "puzzle": 112,
        "rating": 3,
        "session": 2
    }
},
{
    "model": "games.play",
    "pk": 519,
    "fields": {
        "puzzle": 113,
        "rating": 2,
        "session": 2
    }
},
{
    "model": "games.play",
    "pk": 520,
    "fields": {
        "puzzle": 114,
        "rating": 1,
        "session": 2
    }
},
{
    "model": "games.play",
    "pk": 521,
    "fields": {
        "puzzle": 115,
        "rating": 2,
        "session": 2
    }
},
{
    "model": "games.play",
    "pk": 522,
    "fields": {
        "puzzle": 115,
        "rating": 2,
        "session": 2
    }
},
{
    "model": "games.session",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
        "datetime": "2020-10-28T20:26:52.023Z",
        "rating_average": "2.2"
    }
}
]
```

For this specific session (31 plays over 12 puzzles), running the queryset annotation gives an average of `1.0` (same result with limitating the avg_pzl_rating to be averaged with `[:1]`, `[:3]`, `[:8]`), while the direct aggregation on the idividual sessio object gives `2.1527777777777777`

Comment: Imagine you have two sessions, one where you play a puzzle once, and one where you play a puzzle twice, if you calculate the average, is that then the average of the two sessions, thus "inflating" the score of the puzzles of the first session, or do we count this as the average of playing the puzzle three times?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to consider each session individually. Therefore, rating on one session should not have any influence on averages from plays belonging to another session